# Can not show multiple attributes (nested items) in Rails Active Admin Index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have two models product and product_category
A product contains or mapped with multiple product categories and vice versa.
It is maintained through many to many relationships for  which there is another model called products_in_category.
I am using Active Admin for backend and CRUD purpose and now I need to show multiple product_categories in Product index page of Active Admin.
Any suggestion or help will be great for me.

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products_in_categories
    has_many :product_categories, through: :products_in_categories, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_categories   
end

#app/models/product_category.rb
class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products_in_categories
    has_many :products, through: :products_in_categories, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products_in_categories
end

#app/models/products_in_category.rb
class ProductsInCategory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product_category
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list categories names (just change `name` with your actual attribute) in a column:

```
index do
  # other columns goes here
  column('Categories') { |p| p. product_categories.pluck(:name).join(', ') }
end
```

Comment: How about listing all them with <ul> instead of (', ')?